# How to speed up image loading in pillow (python)?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to use pillow for some simple handwritten image recognition, and it will be real-time so I will need to call my function 5-10 times a second. I'm loading the image and am only accessing 1 in 20^2 pixels so I really don't need all the image. I need to reduce the image loading time.

I've never used a python image library and would appreciate all suggestions.

```py
from PIL import Image
import time

start = time.time()

im = Image.open('ir/IMG-1949.JPG')
width, height = im.size
px = im.load()

print("loading: ", time.time() - start)
```

desired loading time: <50ms,
actual loading time: ~150ms

Comment: Can you avoid JPEG - lossless image might be quicker to load?

Comment: How many such images do you have? How many bytes are they on disk? What are their widths and heights?

Comment: I'm using my phone camera for it, the images are 4032 x 3024 - 1.9MB, admidettly the camera is overpowered for the task but it's the only one I have. The default format of the images is JPEG and I will probably not have more then 5 on the disk at any point of time, since they become of no interest after running the code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Since I wrote this answer, John Cupitt (author of `pyvips`) has come up with some improvements and corrections and fairer code and timings and has kindly [shared them here](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/179#issuecomment-618936358). Please look at his improved version, alongside or even in preference to my code below.

**Original Answer**

The JPEG library has a *"shrink-on-load"* feature which allows a lot of I/O and decompression to be avoided. You can take advantage of this with PIL/Pillow using the `Image.draft()` function, so instead of reading the full 4032x3024 pixels like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.jpg')
px = im.load()
```

which takes 297ms on my Mac, you can do the following and read 1008x756 pixels, i.e. 1/4 the width and 1/4 the height:

```
im = Image.open('image.jpg') 
im.draft('RGB',(1008,756)) 
px = im.load()
```

and that takes only 75ms, i.e. it is 4x faster.

---

Just for kicks, I tried comparing various techniques as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import numpy as np 
import pyvips 
import cv2 
from PIL import Image 

def usingPIL(f): 
    im = Image.open(f) 
    return np.asarray(im) 

def usingOpenCV(f): 
    arr = cv2.imread(f,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
    return arr 

def usingVIPS(f): 
    image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(f, access="sequential") 
    return imgnp.numpy() 

def usingPILandShrink(f): 
    im = Image.open(f)  
    im.draft('RGB',(1008,756))  
    return np.asarray(im) 

def usingVIPSandShrink(f): 
    image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(f, access="sequential", shrink=4) 
    return imgnp.numpy()
```

And loaded that into `ipython` and tested like this:

```
%timeit usingPIL('image.jpg')
315 ms ± 8.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit usingOpenCV('image.jpg')
102 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit usingVIPS('image.jpg')
69.1 ms ± 31.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit usingPILandShrink('image.jpg')
77.2 ms ± 994 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit usingVIPSandShrink('image.jpg')                                                    
42.9 ms ± 332 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It seems like **pyVIPS** is the clear winner here!

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, Pillow, image, image processing, JPEG, shrink-on-load, shrink on load, draft mode, read performance, speedup.

Comment: @jcupitt You are absolutely correct - my OpenCV uses `libjpeg-turbo`. I used this handy answer to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281440/2836621 Not sure how to disable it for OpenCV, or how to enable it for PIL and pyvips to make it fairer?

Comment: Those vips results look suspect; 300 times faster than PIL on a large image? In trying out vips on a project of mine, it's actually several times slower than PIL...