# How to check the libjpeg-turbo is built into opencv?

Tags: opencv, libjpeg-turbo

I download the opencv3.4.5 from github https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.5.zip. And the libjpeg-turbo is located at 3rdparty dir.
And build it with `-D WITH_JPEG=ON` and `-D BUILD_JPEG=ON` added. I can check this in CMakeCache.txt. But i cannot find any thing related with `libjpeg-turbo` at install/include or install/lib. How to test and verify the libjpeg-turbo is built into opencv? Instead of system libjpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a binary (executable) in your package called `opencv_version`, which you can run like this:

```
opencv_version -v | grep -i jpeg
```

**Sample Output**

```
JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
```

---

Equally, within Python, you can do:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

Or, maybe more succinctly:

```
import cv2
import re                                                                                   

re.findall('.*jpeg.*',cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

**Sample Output**:

```
['    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)']
```

Comment: Thanks. Does any other differences between libjpeg-turbo and libjpeg? Such as the differences of the API of them, or the effect when use them in jpeg figure.

Comment: And i also try to build `-D WITH_JPEG=ON   -D BUILD_JPEG=OFF`. `./opencv_version -v |grep -i jpeg
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)` The output is the same as the build with `-D WITH_JPEG=ON   -D BUILD_JPEG=ON`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. Are you using C++ or Python? Are you sure you are installing and using the version you are building? I believe the build will take the turbo version if present and the standard version if not. The API is unchanged between the two.

Comment: use c++. I am not a newer to cmake. I do these two tests at two directory. I check the process of `cmake ..` and CMakeCache.txt. It is `JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)` in standard build. The outputs of two tests are the same. `ttt/opencv-3.4.5/build/bin$ ./opencv_version -v |grep -i jpeg
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
`

Comment: Thanks. It may be the reason of my desktop. I do the standard build on another computer. `./opencv_version -v ` is as you said. But it is strange on my desktop.