# Resize to Specific Height and Width with pyvips

Tags: python, image-processing, vips

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57717879/12412938) answer, and I want to use pyvips to resize images. In the mentioned answer and the official [documentation](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/vimage.html#pyvips.Image.resize) image resized by scale. However, I want to resize the image to a specific height and width. Is there any way to achieve this with pyvips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [thumbnail operation](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/vimage.html#pyvips.Image.thumbnail) in pyvips will load an image to fit a box, for example:

```py
thumb = pyvips.Image.thumbnail("some-file.jpg", 128)
```

Will load `some-file.jpg` and make an image that fits within 128x128 pixels. Variations on `thumbnail` can load from strings, buffers or pipes, load to fit other boxes, check the [chapter on vipsthumbnail](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html) for details.

If you already have a loaded image, `thumbnail_image` will resize to pixel dimensions in the same way, but can be quite a bit slower.

Comment: Thumbnail operation crop image or only resize it to the desired size?

Comment: It resizes to fit within the box. It has a mode which will also crop if necessary, but it's not the default. Have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the more general `affine` function.
An affine transformation does `scaling`, `rotation` and `translation` all at once. You can parameterize the affine matrix to do 0 rotation and 0 translation.

You first calculate the necessary factors to achieve the target shape

````
img = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("...")
height_factor = target_height / img.height
width_factor = target_width / img.width```
````

and apply them via

```
img.affine((width_factor, 0, 0, height_factor))
```